# Get "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" configuration value in the code

Tags: magento2

I'm running Magento 2.1.8. How can I get the minimum quantity allowed in shopping value in the code? I want to show this value in the product catalog template `list.phtml` file.

[image]

**Edit:** This is a global value that can be configured in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved this problem. Here's the code.

```
<?php
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $stockObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($_product->getId());
  echo $stockObject->getMinSaleQty();
?>
```

Comment: I have added this confiiguration in my custom module. How can i get values of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the product object and do not want to use the other classes manually. You can try in the following way.

```
$prodObj = $_product->load($_product->getId()); // $_product object in list.phtml
$stockItem = $prodObj->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
$minSaleQty = $stockItem->getMinSaleQty();
```